# Oracle SQL How to use Regex to build a string?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

Using Oracle SQL, how can I go about creating a new string from a larger column string?

E.g. say we have:

```
example-dev5-ex1-ex2
```

as the column. I want to turn that into:

```
example-dev5.ex0.ex1.ex2.
```

ex0 is a hardcoded value that I need to bring into the string. The dev environment could also be dev10, dev11 etc. So another digit on the end of dev.

I'm a complete newbie to regex and can't get my head around it, so any help and an explanation of how it solves this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but it is hard to understand, what you want to do. There are thousands of possibilities to get from string 'example-dev5-ex1-ex2' to 'example-dev5.ex0.ex1.ex2.'. Where does the ex0 for example come from?

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to specify. ex0 will be a hardcoded value.

Comment: That was only an example of what is missing, describe more what you want to do: One example could be: keep everything till the 2nd minus unchanged, add .ex0 to this and then add the rest of the original string where all minuses are replaced by dots.
With your information it is not possible to deduct the rule for the string replacement...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to replace the `-ex??` suffixes so that you always have successive `.ex0` ... `.ex??` suffixes appended then use the regular expression:

```
^([^-]*-[^-]*).*-ex(\d+)$
```

To match the start of the string `^` then the first two hyphen-delimited terms `([^-]*-[^-]*)` then read the rest of the characters `.*` until the final term `-ex(\d+)` at the end-of-the-string `$`.

You can then use the first two terms and the final term in a recursive sub-query factoring clause to generate successive suffixes until you reach the correct depth:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data( value ) AS
  SELECT 'example-dev5-ex1-ex2'   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'example1-dev10-ex3'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'example2-dev99-ex2-ex7' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH rsqfc ( value, max_depth, depth ) AS (
  SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '^([^-]*-[^-]*).*-ex(\d+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 1 ) || '.ex0',
         TO_NUMBER( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '^([^-]*-[^-]*).*-ex(\d+)$', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ) ),
         0
  FROM test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT value || '.ex' || (depth+1),
         max_depth,
         depth + 1
  FROM   rsqfc
  WHERE  depth < max_depth
)
SELECT value
FROM   rsqfc
WHERE  depth = max_depth;
```

**Output**:

```
| VALUE                                          |
| :--------------------------------------------- |
| example-dev5.ex0.ex1.ex2                       |
| example1-dev10.ex0.ex1.ex2.ex3                 |
| example2-dev99.ex0.ex1.ex2.ex3.ex4.ex5.ex6.ex7 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6bc2949267bdf787a46410822e531bb1)*

---

If you just want to add in `.ex0` and change the `-ex??` suffixes to have a `.` at the start then you can use:

**Oracle Query**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '^[^-]*-[^-]*' ) || '.ex0' || REPLACE( REGEXP_SUBSTR( value, '(-ex\d+)+$' ), '-', '.' ) AS value
FROM   test_data
```

**Output**:

```
| VALUE                      |
| :------------------------- |
| example-dev5.ex0.ex1.ex2   |
| example1-dev10.ex0.ex3     |
| example2-dev99.ex0.ex2.ex7 |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6d1c0340afd589cc33010629ebb18902)*

Comment: Thanks MT0, this was incredibly useful!